# How to parse an email from the custom folder from the outlook.office365.com and move it to the another customfolder after processing it?

Tags: email, process, directory

How to parse(retrive) an email from the custom folder from the outlook.office365.com and move it to the another customfolder after processing it?

I have used the Pop3Client but i think it doesn't contain the facility to retrieve email from the specific folder and move that email to another custom folder.

Thanks,
Kandarp